# Difference between Laravel local host and XAMPP local host address

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to learn Laravel, but ran into an issue I hope you can help resolve.  Recently, while working to learn php programming I installed XAMPP, without problem and used it with both php and MYSql.  It uses the localhost IP of http://127.0.0.1.  In the new course I'm using to learn Laravel after the installation of Laravel the setup uses http://127.0.0.1:8000/, which I can access using Visual Code Terminal and entering "php artisan serve".   Following the course instructions for setting up Visual Code I next installed an Extension titled "Connect to Server".  After installation of the extension I get a dialog box to connect to the database and it defaults to the 127.0.0.1:8000/ address.  If I click on the connect button I get an error.  That said, if I start XAMPP and change the value in the dialog box and use the XAMPP 127.0.0.1 address I make a successful connection to MYSQL.The question I have is this, am I going to have a problem in the near future as the result of the two different 127.0.0... addresses and if so is there any way to resolve it?

If you look at the problem I have outlined the issue and hope I can get some resolution before I get to the point I run into trouble.

Comment: `php artisan serve --port=8080` and it will run in the same port as xampp (provided xampp isn't running). For more informtion about different kinds of ports, [**here is the table**](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/15709/port-80)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `php artisan serve` if you wish to use the laravel's serve command. If you wish to use xampp/wamp, you can add a virtual host in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

In case of wamp, httpd-vhosts.conf file is in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf\extra` where 2.4.51 is the apache version if you did not change the installation path.

In case of xampp, it is `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

As for the vhost setup, add the snippet below (change depending on your project path):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "path-to-project\public"
    ServerName project.local
    <Directory "path-to-project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/project-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Next is open your notepad as administrator then go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` then open hosts file. add `127.0.0.1 project.local`

restart wamp/xampp. You should be able to access your project using `project.local`

Answer (score 0):

Xampp comes with Apcahe/ Mysql so when you run xampp it runs apache and mysql both.
but `php artisan serve` starts only a php server so your database related thins will not work if you are not running mysql separately (With xampp or as a standalone installation)

You can find more about what the artisan serve command to here [PHP artisan serve code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7392f1beb710d021c6e1e0749b06911e8faa6943/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php#L161)